# Does opponent process happen in the retina or in the brain?

Tags: vision

I understand that both the Trichromatic Process and the Opponent Process take place in human vision.
Trichromatic Process is widely accepted to happen in the retina,
however I heard differing accounts of where Opponent Process happens - in the retina or in the LGN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opponent process happens BOTH in the retina, and in the brain (Lateral Geniculate Nucleus).

Here is the excerpt from *Vision Science: Photons to Phenomenology* by *Stephen E. Palmer*:

**In the brain** (LGN):

> Physiological psychologist Russell De Valois (1965) and his colleagues (De Valois, Abramov, &
>   Jacobs, 1966) measured responses in the **LGN** of macaque monkeys and
>   discovered color-selective cells whose responses to wavelengths of
>   light were incompatible with trichromatic theory but conformed roughly
>   to the pattern predicted by Hering's opponent process theory. Some
>   were excited by red light and inhibited by green (R+G- cells). Others responded in the opposite way,
>   exciting to green and inhibiting to red (G+R- cells). In addition,
>   they found cells that were excited by yellow and inhibited by blue
>   (Y+B- cells) as well as ones showing the reverse pattern of responses
>   (B+Y- cells). Together, these **LGN** cells can reasonably be interpreted
>   as a neural implementation of Hering's opponent process theory.

**In the retina**:

> Further research has shown that these patterns of response are also
>   present in the **bipolar and ganglion cells of the retina**. Output of R+G- opponent cells can be derived by combining excitatory
>   input from the L cones and the inhibitory input from M cones,
>   essentially computing the difference between the output of these two
>   cone systems (L - M).